# Creating glibc 2.7 style Sha-512 crypt hashes in Perl

Tags: perl, cryptography, passwords, salt, password-encryption

So, I have a website that reads/verifies (and writes) password hashes from the database, and I have something that makes SHA-512 style password hashes for that, ones that look like:

```
$6$GloHensinmyampOc$AxvlkxxXk36oDOyu8phBzbCfLn8hyWgoYNEuqNS.3dHf4JJrwlYCqha/g6pA7HJ1WwsADjWU4Qz8MfSWM2w6F.
```

The website is java based, so I wrote a SHA-512 hasher for it. Trouble is, there are a bunch of perl cron jobs that run that **also** need to verify password hashes occasionally to the database, and since those run on a Solaris box, it's crypt doesn't support the $6$ format.

So, when I do:

```
printf("crypt => '%s'\n",crypt("Hello",'$1$CygnieHyitJoconf$'));
```

I get back sensibly:

```
crypt => '$1$CygnieHy$n9MlDleP0qmGCfpbnVYy11'
```

Whereas, if I do

```
printf("crypt => '%s'\n",crypt("Hello",'$6$CygnieHyitJoconf$'));
```

I get an unhelpful

```
crypt => ''
```

Is there a way to get the SHA-512 password hashes in Perl on a box that isn't using glibc? (That's what I get told when I do a search mostly ("use crypt").

I'd really rather not re-implement SHA-512 password hashes in perl.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Actually, I think I just found my own answer: [Crypt::Passwd::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Crypt%3A%3APasswd%3A%3AXS)

Crypt::Passwd::XS - Full XS implementation of common crypt() algorithms

It does unix_md5, apache_md5, unix_des, unix_sha256 and unix_sha512.. I guess it's a little unfortunate that it doesn't do blowfish. But, nevertheless, it solves my problem! Thanks @hobbs anyway tho!

```
use strict;
use Crypt::Passwd::XS;

{
        printf("crypt => %s\n",Crypt::Passwd::XS::crypt("Hello",'$6$CygnieHyitJoconf$'));
}
```

Now returns

```
crypt => $6$CygnieHyitJoconf$vkGJm.nLrFhyWHhNTvOh9fH/k7y6k.8ed.N7TqwT93hPMPfAOUsrRiO3MmQB5xTm1XDCVlW2zwyzU48epp8pY/
```

as expected!

Comment: Oh, the amusing Irony.  A module named "Crypt::Passwd::XS" which contains ONLY algorithms that you should NEVER use for passwords!!!  bcrypt or PBKDF* guys, and if you don't understand why, you better go read up.  It's subtle, but is only the difference between "useless" and "works" !!

Comment: Really? Why shouldn't you use unix_sha512? It salts, and so far as I know it's still collision resistant.. ?

Comment: For the record, glibc's implementation is not a simple salt 'n hash operation, which would indeed be pretty useless in the face of attack given how ridiculously easy (fast) it is for computers to compute SHA hashes. Refer to this 2007 article written by the developer who designed it: http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/sha-crypt.html ... From a quick persual of the page bnsh linked, I'm guessing this perl module is based on the same design, which would render @cnd's argument baseless.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not. `crypt` will be your system libc `crypt`, which is responsible for choosing algorithms and mapping prefix strings to algorithms. If you want access to algorithms that aren't in your system `crypt` then you'll need to use a re-implementation of them, and in the case of the libc ones, I don't know of any reimplementations. glibc's "SHA-512" password hash isn't simply SHA-512; it's a custom algorithm that doesn't exist outside of glibc that I know of. If you still have a chance, you might want to change to an algorithm like bcrypt or PBKDF-SHA-2 that has multiple implementations in different languages.

Comment: It is not so much a custom algorithm as it is a different algorithm. It is sha512crypt. SHA512 is designed to be FAST, which is the opposite of what you want for a password hashing function. It follows the crypt(3) standard along with bcrypt, and supports variable complexity (a variable number of 'rounds' to make it stronger in the future when the default 5000 rounds is not enough anymore). crypt(3) is always what you should use for password hashing. nothing else, ever.